# converter from roman numbers to arabic numbers

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to write program to convert roman numbers (like MCLII) into arabic numbers. After hours spending in front of the computer and textbook I have a code that is not completed. Please help me find out why the program is wrong and does not print anything at the end. thank you

```
public class Main {
public static void romanToDecimal(java.lang.String romanNumber) {
int decimal = 0;
int lastNumber = 0;
String romanNumeral = romanNumber.toUpperCase();

for (int x = romanNumeral.length() - 1; x >= 0 ; x--)
{
    char convertToDecimal = romanNumeral.charAt(x);

    switch (convertToDecimal)
    {
        case 'M':
            decimal = processDecimal(1000, lastNumber, decimal);
            lastNumber = 1000;
            break;

        case 'D':
            decimal = processDecimal(500, lastNumber, decimal);
            lastNumber = 500;
            break;

        case 'C':
            decimal = processDecimal(100, lastNumber, decimal);
            lastNumber = 100;
            break;

        case 'L':
            decimal = processDecimal(50, lastNumber, decimal);
            lastNumber = 50;
            break;

        case 'X':
            decimal = processDecimal(10, lastNumber, decimal);
            lastNumber = 10;
            break;

        case 'V':
            decimal = processDecimal(5, lastNumber, decimal);
            lastNumber = 5;
            break;

        case 'I':
            decimal = processDecimal(1, lastNumber, decimal);
            lastNumber = 1;
            break;
    }
 }
 System.out.println(decimal);
 }

 public static int processDecimal(int decimal, int lastNumber, int lastDecimal)
 {
 if (lastNumber > decimal)
 {
    return lastDecimal - decimal;
 } else {
    return lastDecimal + decimal;
 }
 }

 public static void main(java.lang.String args[]) {
 System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER ANY NUMBER IN ROMAN NUMERIC FORMAT:");
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int romanToDecimal;
 romanToDecimal = input.nextInt();
 }
 }
```

Comment: I've just noticed that you're reading the Roman number from right to left.  That's really good thinking.  Ingenious - I'm +1'ing your question just for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you're asking them to enter something that consists of letters, you're trying to read it using `nextInt()`.  That's not going to work.  `nextInt()` only reads digits.

And as another answer has pointed out, you'll need to actually *call* the `romanToDecimal` method, which you're not doing.

Comment: ok nextInt() does not working, perfect..... I can not find out how to call romanToDecimal method to print out correct thing.

Comment: ok I find out if I put into romanToDecimal(XL) will print out 40, but if I put romanToDecimal(input) shows as an error, thats very interesting situation:)

Comment: Not sure why you're writing that on MY answer.  You should never have written `romanToDecimal(input)`, because `input` is a `Scanner`, but `romanToDecimal` needs a `String`.  You're going to need to find a way to use the `Scanner` to get a `String` from the input.

Comment: I know you are trying to help as much as you can, but I am completely lost right now, and do not know how to fix that problem, can you help?

Comment: OK, there are a couple of methods of the `Scanner` class that you can use to get a `String` from the input.  One is `next()`, and the other is `nextLine()`.  I think `next()` will probably work quite well here.  So you probably want to write something like `String romanNumeral = input.next();` and then `romanToDecimal(romanNumeral);`

Comment: I have done little different and work perfect as well, thank you for your time, now I have some different case and is about the game Tic-Tac-Toe, I will post the code I have later on. I think this is the most difficult thing I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

you are not calling any method,so it will not do anything.Only this will be printed

```
 System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER ANY NUMBER IN ROMAN NUMERIC FORMAT:");
```

Call the methods like

```
romanToDecimal("some tring");
```

So you are taking inputs from user from the console

so do this way

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
romanToDecimal(input);
```

Comment: Ooooo thats the problem, output method is missing, thanks I will try do something.

Comment: I am going to be honest, still cant find out which method I should do, trying so many options now and none is working. I am starting to loosing my mind. I think I will from the beginning.

Comment: He/she should only accept it if it solves his/her problem, which it doesn't.  Nobody should accept answers because the respondent pressures them to do so.

Comment: @DavidWallace you got me wrong,you might not have read that line properly.I asked if help full then you can.So this does not pressure any body.i would have written you have to/you should.

Comment: ok I find out if I put into romanToDecimal(XL) will print out 40, but if I put romanToDecimal(input) shows as an error, thats very interesting situation:)

Comment: what is the input datatype,it will give error if its not string

Comment: I am lost right now, I deleted all and started from scratch again, but I still have the same issue, this is making me so frustrated, I tried to put String for input but that does not working as well, can you guys help?

Comment: @user2900919 congrats